# docker warning config.json permission denied

Tags: permissions, docker

I just installed docker and created a group and added my username to it to avoid using sudo every time. However when I do the test and run `docker run hello-world` it gives me following error:
`WARNING: Error loading config file:/home/user/.docker/config.json - stat /home/user/.docker/config.json: permission denied`

But then it continues and gives a success message:`Hello from Docker.
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.`

Any ideas whats wrong and what implications does it have?

Comment: The official documentation has a nice section named [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/).

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Try running

```
sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
sudo chmod g+rwx "/home/$USER/.docker" -R
```

`$USER` is the username of the currently logged in user.

Comment: thanks, that seem to have done it. Just a question, since I changed ownership to my user. Would it be better to change ownership to a group: docker?

Comment: was a bit too fast and ran command from earlier root login. I still get the same error.  I even tried running: `sudo chown user:docker /home/user/.docker/config.json`, but it didn't help

Comment: Hmm :/ What's the output of `ls -la /home/user/.docker/` @Trm ?

Comment: Hi. I moved away the file and everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: Cool @Trm I wonder if you maybe needed to do `chown -R USER:DOCKER /home/USER/.docker` ?

Comment: I haven't tried to chown dir itself but only the file directly (see 2nd comment). I'm quite new to Linux, but is there a difference `chown -R USER:DOCKER /home/USER/.docker` vs  `chown user:docker /home/user/.docker/config.json` for this specific file?

Comment: `chown -R USER:DOCKER /home/USER/.docker` sets the permissions for the directory and all its files. `chown user:docker /home/user/.docker/config.json` will do just the file.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -la /home/user/.docker`?

Comment: `drwx------  2 root   root   4096 mar 18 19:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 47 user user 4096 mar 20 15:22 ..
-rw-------  1 user docker  131 mar 18 19:59 config.json`

Comment: I've got it! Try running `sudo chmod -R g+rw /home/user/.docker`

Comment: Perfect works like a charm now. If I understand correctly, while I owned the file, I did not have rw permissions and now I added them?

Comment: No, @Trm you had write permissions. `-rw-------` means only you have permissions. Not the group. g+rw adds read/write permissions to anyone in the docker group

Comment: ok. many thanks for your time! much appreciated.

Comment: If you set the .docker folder as `g+rw` docker group members can not read the files inside the folder, only list them. To read files in a folder you need also execute permission (`g+rwx` ) on that folder.

Comment: For the lazy: `sudo chown $(whoami):docker /home/$(whoami)/.docker/config.json` 
just copy paste.